# Add ajaxresponse inside a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I have made an ajax call to backend using the following code:

```
<script >
 var frm = $('#identity');
 var textare = $('#textare');

 textare.keyup(function() {
   $.ajax({
       type: frm.attr('method'),
       url: "{% url 'creatd-new' %}",
       data: frm.serialize(),
       success: function (data) {
           $('#some_div').html(data.is_true);
       },
   });
       return false;
 });
 </script>
```

backend dumps a "is_true" in the JsonResponse which successfully gets printed but when I try to print the same value of "is_true" inside a text area,it is not working.
I have tried the following:

```
$('#some_div').html( <textarea rows="4" cols="50">data.is_true</textarea> );

$('#some_div').val( <textarea rows="4" cols="50">data.is_true</textarea> );

$('#some_div').append( <textarea rows="4" cols="50">data.is_true</textarea> );
```

but these are not working.

Comment: you have to append to div as a string using quotes ""

Comment: $('#some_div').append( '<textarea rows="4" cols="50">'+data.is_true+'</textarea>' );

Comment: You are writing the javascript code within <script> tag. This will execute as soon as the page starts loading. If the above comment hasn't worked, can you try this code on 'onload' event of the page to make sure that the textarea exists when the script runs.

Comment: As Mohit pointed it,it helped me a lot.I used $('#some_div').html( '<textarea rows="4" cols="50">'+data.is_true+'</textarea>' );